# Fastest way to get liquidity pool creation event

Tags: rpc, logs

What is the fastest way to get liquidity pool creation event?
I have tried using popular rpc webhook and logs subscribe websockets but I end up receiving the creation event about 5 seconds behind the first swap transaction of the liquidity pool meaning I am receiving it way slower than others. I have tried using wss node rpc with logs filter method, same issue. I even set commitment to processed but I am always at least 3 seconds behind the first swap. So how are these guys doing it?